# Spring @ModelAttribute not mapping request in case of put request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, modelattribute

I am using `Spring Boot` and `JAX-RS`.

I am trying to map `multipart/form-data` having files into  `@ModelAttribute` for `PUT` request which isn't working. its not mapping any field.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/category/{courseCategoryId}",
  method = RequestMethod.PUT,
  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
  consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> updateCourseCategory(
  @PathVariable("courseCategoryId") long courseCategoryId,
  @ModelAttribute CourseCategory category) {
  // code 
}
```

### CourseCategory.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course_category")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
property  = "id",
scope     = Long.class)
@DynamicInsert(true)
@DynamicUpdate(true)
public class CourseCategory implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -596261264681151471L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    @Transient
    private MultipartFile imageFile;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "description", columnDefinition = "Text", length = 50000)
    private String description;

    @Column(name= "active", columnDefinition="tinyint(1) default 1")
    private boolean active = true;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Courses> courses;


    public void setImageFile(MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException {
        if(imageFile != null) {
            this.imageUrl = DefaultConfig.uploadFile(imageFile);
        }
        this.imageFile = null;
    }


    public void setCourses(List<Courses> courses) {
        courses.forEach(course -> course.setCategory(this));
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    // other getters and setters
}
```

I don't want to use `HttpServletRequest` is there any configuration or way to get it in working condition.

Comment: can you able to show your model `CourseCategory`

Comment: I strongly recommended you to use your own business class for `ModelAttribute` (Not the database object). Anyways, did you configure any multipart resolver for your project ? Which error do you see in the console ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna: its not throwing any error just not setting any value to data members they all are null.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna: i tried to set it using customDTO but didn't worked same issue. everything is working fine on post but is not supported with put request.

Comment: It seems that @ModelAttribute only supports GET and POST mapping.